# SQL Server : merge two tables content in one view and order by

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have two tables:

- `dbo.clients`
- `dbo.employee`

and I need to create a view which:

- merges names and surnames with those 2 tables (clients & employee)
- sorts the output by surname descending

At the moment I have this:

```
create view dbo.people
as
    select top 100 
        imię, nazwisko 
    from klienci 
    order by nazwisko desc

    union all

    select top 100 
        imię, nazwisko 
    from pracownicy
    order by nazwisko desc
```

legend:

- imię = name
- nazwisko = surname

but the output is wrong, because there are 2 different sorts instead of 1 of overall

look at the screenshot:
[image]

I hope u will understand me, and help me :)

Thanks

Comment: In a relational database views don't have an order. If you want a particular order you should specify it in the select from the view.

Comment: could You tell me how?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM dbo.people order by nazwisko desc`